# CheckBox not staying at bottom of dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

In my custom dialog, I am trying to get my checkbox to stay underneath my scrollview but it's not working. I've tried adding the checkbox under the scrollview in xml but it doesn't appear whenever I run the app. What needs to be done in order for the checkbox to remain at the bottom of the dialog (underneath the scrollview), and not be part of the scrollview when I scroll that? I don't want my checkbox to scroll with the scrollview at all.

**java**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overlay, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.Overlay_linearLayout));
AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
db.setView(dialog_layout);
db.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
});
db.show();
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Overlay_linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Overlay_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Overlay_tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <TableRow
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_0" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView0"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction0" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_1" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction1" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_2" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction2" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_3" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView3"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction3"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <CheckBox
                android:text="Don't show this again"
                android:id="@+id/skip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Pull the `CheckBox` out of the `ScrollView`, and put them both inside another `ViewGroup`; e.g., a vertically-oriented `LinearLayout`.

Comment: keep `checkbox` outside `ScrollView` and wrap both `ScrollView` and `CheckBox` in `LinearLayout`

Comment: okey you can also use `RelativeLayout` and add `android:alignParentBottom="true"` to check box. EDIT : you can replace second parameter with null `View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overlay, null);`

Comment: Change the `ScrollView`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and set its `layout_weight` to `1`.

Comment: @MikeM. problem solved many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `checkbox` and `ScrolView` inside of new `LinearLayout` and put `checkbox` outside the `ScrollView` like this :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/Overlay_scrollView"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/Overlay_tableLayout"
                     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:weightSum="1.0">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView0"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="tion0"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView1"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="dada"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="ruction2"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView3"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="_instruction3"/>


        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Don't show this again"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

How to inflate `xml` file and set it to `dialog`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

Comment: What about this line of code? `View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overlay, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.Overlay_linearLayout));`

Comment: Checkbox doesn't appear

Comment: hmm in my sim its appear with this code http://s27.postimg.org/539925183/Screenshot_8.png , and for inflater why did you not inflate the whole xml layout

Comment: I don't know how to inflate the whole xml layout.

Comment: what param is you set to ScrolView height?

Comment: The last comment MikeM made solved the issue, although please update your answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your layout file. It is your xml file with some modifications.

```
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Overlay_linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/Overlay_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/skip">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/Overlay_tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView0"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction0" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView1"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView2"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapOverlay_textView3"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="@string/overlay_instruction3" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/skip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Don't show this again" />
```